# Articulated animation

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I am trying to figure out how to sequence the train animation so I can offset and rotate each wagon in turn around curves, for example, in Route_51 (click Test>Run[twice]) in [this display](http://glasier.hk/machine/machine.php). Needs Chrome or other HTML5 compliant browser.

Here is my so far 'non-complying' code (using KineticJs):

```
function animate(nr,path,incr,train,dirX,dirY){
var steps,offsetX,offsetY,count,a;
steps = Math.round(path[nr][2] / incr);
offsetX = path[nr][2]/steps;
offsetY = path[nr][3]/steps;
count = 0;
stage.onFrame(function(frame){
    layer = train[0].getLayer();
    if(count < steps){
        for(a=0; a<train.length; a+=1){ 
            incrX = train[a].getX() + offsetX * -dirX;
            incrY = train[a].getY() - offsetY * -dirY;
            train[a].setX(incrX);
            train[a].setY(incrY);
        }
        layer.draw();
        count += 1;
    }
    else{
        stage.stop();
        nr += 1;
        if(path[nr]){
            animate(nr,path,incr,train,dirX,dirY);
        }
    }
});
stage.start();
```

}

I don't seem to be able to grasp the logic (getting old).

All help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a certain amount of time has to pass before some kind of logic emerges.

In this case it was that each loco/wagon needed its own fully incremented path for the starts and optionally finishes to be staggered. Here is a screenshot of the train in motion with the "normal" scale view inset. Room for improvement of course especially with curve coordinates.

[image]

For the animation visit http://glasier.hk and follow the KJS link.